# bash shell append to variable frustration

Tags: bash, shell

So I have a relatively simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare ALL="";
while IFS="" read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]
do
   if [[ $line == 'ENV ms'* ]]; then
      words=( $line )
      if [[ ${#ALL} > 0 ]]; then
         ALL="$ALL;${words[1]}=${words[2]}"
      else
         ALL="${words[1]}=${words[2]}"
      fi

      if [[ ${#ALL} > 0 ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$ALL"
        echo "${#ALL}"
      fi

   fi
done < Dockerfile


echo "$ALL"
echo "${#ALL}"
```

parsing a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
#
# Configuration Stage
#
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-12 AS build

ENV HOME=/usr/local/ms-cards

RUN mkdir -p $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

COPY maven-settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
COPY pom.xml $HOME

RUN mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean verify --fail-never

COPY . $HOME

RUN mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package

#
# Package stage
#
FROM openjdk:12
COPY --from=build /usr/local/ms-cards/target/ms-cards-1.0-exec.jar /usr/local/lib/ms-cards.jar
ENV ms_oauth_ip ms-oauth
ENV ms_oauth_port 48001
ENV ms_cards_client_id clientapp
ENV ms_cards_client_secret 123456
ENV ms_cards_port 48002
ENV ms_connection_port 48003
ENV ms_connection_ip ms-connection
EXPOSE 48002
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/ms-cards.jar"]
```

and it gives me this output:

```
ms_oauth_ip=ms-oauth
21
;ms_oauth_port=48001
42
;ms_cards_client_id=clientapp
72
;ms_cards_client_secret=123456
103
;ms_cards_port=48002ret=123456
124
;ms_connection_port=4800323456
150
;ms_connection_ip=ms-connection
182
;ms_connection_ip=ms-connection
182
```

So I can see that my ALL variable is growing in length...but when printf'ing it never seems to be growing...Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dockerfile` has Windows `\r\n` line endings. Each `\r` that is printed causes the cursor to jump back to the beginning of the line and overwrite the previous setting.

Debugging tip: Use `declare -p var` to see exactly what's in a variable.

Comment: Thanks John.  I support Monica now too.